# Grub-install: what's the root directory

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, grub

Can anyone provide a clear explanation what the root directory is for `grub-install` and when to use it?

Comment: Did you mean boot directory? `grub-install` doesn't need the root directory at all.

Comment: @YoMismo No, I meant root directory. See man

Comment: I did, root search returns: `Pattern not found  (press RETURN)` at least in my version (1.99-27+deb7u2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root directory is just what it says: your root directory, i.e /.  If you are running `grub-install` while booted from some other medium and have your normal root directory mounted somewhere other than /, then you want to specify this argument to point it to your root directory.

Comment: An nice explanation is [here](http://www.av8n.com/computer/htm/grub-reinstall.htm#sec-grub-install): _"The --root-directory=/x option tells grub where to look for the grub directory during the installation process. The grub directory is /x/boot/grub on typical distributions such as Ubuntu and Debian, but may be /x/grub on some *bsd setups. ... the inode of interest will be reached by the path "/x" during the installation process. Grub assumes this inode will be reached by the simple path "/" later .... This distinction is, alas, not well documented._

Comment: Apparently the `grub-install` of the original grub had the option `--root-directory`, but `grub-install` of grub2 has option `--boot-directory`: _--boot-directory=DIR: Use DIR as the boot directory. The default is /boot. GRUB will put its files in a subdirectory of this directory named grub._

Comment: @DavidTonhofer You should convert your comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too much of an expert about GRUB, but as far as I know, the root directory for GRUB it's the directory where you can install a working GRUB when you have started your system in recovery mode:

`grub-install –-root-directory=/test/kernelimage /dev/sda`

Here the root directory contains an image of the Linux kernel to boot, and must also contain a directory `/boot/grub`.